# Where did quantum numbers arise from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I was told that there are 4 quantum numbers which help in locating the position of an electron inside an atom. And they are

1. Principal quantum number
2. Azimuthal quantum number
3. Spin quantum number
4. Magnetic quantum number

I was also told what they specify individually. Now I was wondering how physicists came up with this. Is it theoritical or experimental result?

Wondering about this I started searching online for answers. And according to my research they are special solutions to schroedinger wave equation, which says that it's theoritical result.

**MY QUESTION**

1. How to prove that quantum numbers are special solutions to schroedinger equation mathematically??

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Schr%C3%B6dinger_solution) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction).

Comment: Have you tried to solve the Schrödinger equation for a Coulomb potential?